Flutter Error: The getter 'popDisposition' isn't defined for the class 'PageRoute<T>'
I'm having a problem. I'm working in a flutter project since many month and it run without any problem. But since few times, i'm getting the following problem in console every times that i run "flutter run".
Here is the content of my console: ICI
The more strange is that i haven't made any change in my pubspec.yaml an it's talking about a stacked-3.4.4 library.
Here is the pubspec.yaml
name: enzo
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.2.0+27

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  qr_flutter: ^4.0.0
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.1.0
  country_icons: ^2.0.2
  smooth_page_indicator: ^1.0.0+2
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.13
  provider: ^6.0.3
  flutter_svg: ^1.0.3
  flutter_local_notifications: ^9.1.4
  carousel_slider: ^4.1.1
  dio: ^4.0.6
  video_player: ^2.4.5
  direct_link: ^0.1.9
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.1.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.3
  json_annotation: ^4.9.0
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.8
  flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.1
  dropdown_button2: ^2.3.9
  google_fonts: ^4.0.4
  country_code_picker: ^3.0.0
  visibility_detector: ^0.2.1
  #loader_overlay: ^3.0.3
  flutter_staggered_animations: ^1.0.0
  webview_flutter: ^3.0.0
  flutter_facebook_auth: ^3.5.7
  google_sign_in: ^5.0.3
  #firebase_auth: ^4.6.3
  #firebase_core: ^2.14.0
  #stacked_card_carousel: ^0.0.3-nullsafety.1
  kkiapay_flutter_sdk: ^1.1.0
  permission_handler: ^10.0.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.11
  image_picker: ^0.8.6
  image_gallery_saver: ^1.7.1
  responsive_sizer: ^3.1.1
  share_plus: ^6.3.0
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: ^0.18.0
  circle_flags: ^0.0.3
  flutter_cached_pdfview: ^0.4.3
  #loading_animation_widget: 1.2.0
  #uiblock: 2.0.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner: ^2.1.11
  json_serializable: ^6.2.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2
  flutter_app_name: ^0.1.0

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0

flutter_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/logos/logo1.png"
  remove_alpha_ios: true

flutter_app_name:
  name: "MyCanalOlympia"


# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  generate: true
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/images/
    - assets/docs/
    - assets/docs/cgu.pdf
    - assets/icons/
    - assets/logos/
    - assets/board/
    - assets/board/svg/
#  fonts:
#    - family: Open Sans
#      fonts:
#        - asset: assets/fonts/opensansbold700.ttf
#          weight: 700
#        - asset: assets/fonts/opensansopensans400.ttf
#          weight: 400
#        - asset: assets/fonts/opensansopensansromanextrabold800.ttf
#          weight: 800
#        - asset: assets/fonts/opensansopensansromansemibold600.ttf
#          weight: 600
#        - asset: assets/fonts/opensanslight300.ttf
#          weight: 300
#        - asset: assets/fonts/opensanssemibold600.ttf
#          weight: 600
#    - family: Roboto
#      fonts:
#        - asset: assets/fonts/robotoregular400.ttf
#          weight: 400
flutter_intl:
  enabled: true
analyzer:
  strong-mode: true
  language:
    enableSuperMixins: true

Here is the flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.6, on Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.19045.5247], locale fr-FR)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.11.5)
    X Visual Studio is missing necessary components. Please re-run the Visual Studio installer for the "Desktop development with C++" workload, and include these
      components:
        MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools
         - If there are multiple build tool versions available, install the latest
        C++ CMake tools for Windows
        Windows 10 SDK
[√] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
[√] VS Code (version 1.95.3)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] Network resources


Any help would be appreciated. I'm struggling since many days but found nothing.
Every time that i run the project it still fails no matter what i do.
